# Android using Kotlin while building the app

Tags: kotlin

This error keeps popping up when I try to build this app.

> Caused by:
> org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException:
> A failure occurred while executing
> com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable

Answer (score 0):

**Add this line to gradle.properties.**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
```